# What is $\Im\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b-i}}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is: $$\Im\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b-i}}\right)$$Where $b$ is a real number.

I tried and couldn't do it. Please answer it if you can.

Edit: I tried to ged rid of the $i$ in denominator by multiplying $\sqrt{\frac{b-i}{b-i}}$ and $\frac{b+i}{b+i}$

Then I got stuck. Dont know how to deal with

$\Im\left((b+i)\left(\sqrt{b-i}\right)\right)$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than votes to close or downvotes if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: "I tried and couldn't do it". But what have you tried?

Comment: @idk I tried to ged rid of the i in denominator by multiplying $\sqrt{\frac{b-i}{b-i}\}$ and $\frac{b+i}{b+i}\$ Then I got stuck

Comment: Please include that in your question.

Comment: Square roots are not single valued in the complex plane. You also need to describe a branch cut.

Comment: Polar form is better suited to take powers, multiplication and division. $b-i=\sqrt{b^2+1}\exp(i\arctan(-1/b))$. The square root would be $(b^2+1)^{1/4}\exp(i\arctan(-1/b)/2)$, and its reciprocal $(b^2+1)^{-1/4}\exp(-i\arctan(-1/b)/2)$. You can finally take imaginary part: $(b^2+1)^{-1/4}\sin(-\arctan(-1/b)/2)$

Comment: [MSE-$\texttt{MathJax}$ Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You're heading in a good direction with your idea of multiplying top and bottom by the same thing to make the bottom nicer (which in this case would mean making it a pure real). And you tried the conjugate (i.e. $b+i$) and using a square root,  but I think you'll have the better luck if you use both, i.e. multiply by $$ \dfrac{\sqrt{b+i}}{\sqrt{b+i}}$$

From the statement of your question it looks like you're looking for a 'simplification', and it's not always clear what 'simplification' means. If you need to remove all references to imaginary numbers it'll get messy, and YAlexandrov's comment shows what you can expect.

Comment: Ok Ill try it later! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> We   obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\Im\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b-i}}\right)}&=\Im\left((b-i)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)\\
> &=\Im\left(\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Log}(b-i)\right)\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\Im\left(\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\ln|b-i|-\frac{i}{2}\mathrm{Arg}(b-i)\right)\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\Im\left(|b-i|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2}\mathrm{Arg}(b-i)\right)\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\Im\left((b^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\left[\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Arg}(b-i)\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Arg}(b-i)\right)\right]\right)\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-(b^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Arg}(b-i)\right)}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the representation as *[Principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value)* of the complex logarithm.
- In (2) we write the principal value using the real logarithm $\ln$ and the argument $\mathrm{Arg}$.
- In (3) we factor out $|b-i|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.
- In (4) we write the absolute value $|b-i|=(b^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and apply *[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)*.
- In (5) we select the imaginary part.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!

Comment: @user539463: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're working with a *square* root, you don't necessarily need to invoke polar form or trigonometric functions:
$$\sqrt{u+v\mathrm{i}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}+u}{2}}+\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{sgn}\,v\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}-u}{2}}\quad(u\neq 0\text{ or } v\geq 0)$$
(Abramowitz and Stegun [3.2.27](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_17.htm); when $u^2+v^2=1$, this equality reduces to the [half-angle formulae](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.21#E21) for trigonometric functions.)

Then
$$\begin{split}\Im\frac{1}{\sqrt{b-\mathrm{i}}}&=\frac{\Im((b+\mathrm{i})\sqrt{b-\mathrm{i}})}{b^2+1}\\
&=\frac{b\Im\sqrt{b-\mathrm{i}}+\Re\sqrt{b-\mathrm{i}}}{b^2+1}\\
&=\frac{-b\sqrt{2(\sqrt{b^2+1}-b)}+\sqrt{2(\sqrt{b^2+1}+b)}}{2(b^2+1)}
\end{split}$$
which is a "simplification" in that trigonometric functions have been eliminated in favor of real square roots.